# Magento export error

Tags: php, magento

I have an extension called 'Custom Bulk Product Import + Export with Tier Pricing / Custom Options / Configurable and Bundle Pro' installed and when I try exporting products all I see is 'Starting profile execution, please wait...' and nothing happens. I've increased memory and exceeded time limit but problem is still there. I checked php error logs and this is the error I receive:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'CommerceExtensions_Productimportexport_Model_Convert_Adapter_Productimport' not found in /home1/darrosme/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Action/Abstract.php on line 182

Developer says it's something that has to do with server or permissions and hosting should help but hosting support says it is related to code not server. Please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will be check 2 method in your question.

1. file exist ?
   /home1/darrosme/public_html/store/app/code/{community or local}/commerce_extensions/productimportexport/Model/convert/adapter/productimport ?
2. you compiled magento ?

   - recompile

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_compiler/process/index

Answer (score 0):

Please disable this extension CommerceExtensions_Productimportexport then check after refresh cache.